# Function from_tensor_slices() try to allocate 30Go of memory but my datasets is actually of 500Mo

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I'm working on my first GAN to generate some images. My training datasets are 80'000 images of 128x128 pixels for a total size of 500Mo.
I use this code for creating my datasets :

```
# Get all the images path
imgsPath = getAllImagesPath(ROOT_PATH)

# Load each image
data_imgs = []
for imgPath in imgsPath:
    img = cv2.imread(imgPath)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)   # Convert BGR -> RGB
    data_imgs.append(img)

# Convert to numpy array
data_imgs = np.array(data_imgs)

# Normalize the images to [-1, 1]
data_imgs = (data_imgs - 127.5) / 127.5
```

And then :

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data_imgs)
```

But when I'm running this line, I get this error :

```
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595043: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:479] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 29.17GiB (rounded to 31323193344)requested by op _EagerConst
If the cause is memory fragmentation maybe the environment variable 'TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR=cuda_malloc_async' will improve the situation. 
Current allocation summary follows.
Current allocation summary follows.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595446: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1027] BFCAllocator dump for GPU_0_bfc
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595474: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (256):     Total Chunks: 2, Chunks in use: 2. 512B allocated for chunks. 512B in use in bin. 9B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595491: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (512):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595516: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (1024):     Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 1.2KiB allocated for chunks. 1.2KiB in use in bin. 1.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595530: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (2048):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595543: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (4096):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595555: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (8192):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595568: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (16384):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595581: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (32768):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595593: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (65536):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595605: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (131072):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595618: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (262144):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595630: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (524288):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B 
allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595643: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (1048576):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595655: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (2097152):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595668: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (4194304):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595681: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (8388608):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595693: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (16777216):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595706: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (33554432):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595718: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (67108864):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595735: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (134217728):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.595752: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (268435456):     Total Chunks: 2, Chunks in use: 1. 10.17GiB allocated for chunks. 7.32GiB in use in bin. 7.32GiB client-requested in use in bin.
2022-08-29 07:30:29.596097: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1050] Bin for 29.17GiB was 256.00MiB, Chunk State: 
2022-08-29 07:30:29.596138: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1056]   Size: 2.84GiB | Requested Size: 0B | in_use: 0 | bin_num: 20, prev:   Size: 256B | Requested Size: 1B | in_use: 1 | bin_num: -1
2022-08-29 07:30:29.596150: I tensorflow/core/common_runt

 

InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/hesID22gr3/covers-source/GAN.ipynb Cell 5 in <cell line: 4>()
      1 # Batch and shuffle the data
      2 BATCH_SIZE = 256
----> 4 train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data_imgs)
      5 train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)

 

File ~/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py:809, in DatasetV2.from_tensor_slices(tensors, name)
    731 @staticmethod
    732 def from_tensor_slices(tensors, name=None):
    733   """Creates a `Dataset` whose elements are slices of the given tensors.
    734 
    735   The given tensors are sliced along their first dimension. This operation
   (...)
    807     Dataset: A `Dataset`.
    808   """
--> 809   return TensorSliceDataset(tensors, name=name)

 

File ~/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py:4551, in TensorSliceDataset.__init__(self, element, is_files, name)
   4549 def __init__(self, element, is_files=False, name=None):
   4550   """See `Dataset.from_tensor_slices()` for details."""
-> 4551   element = structure.normalize_element(element)
   4552   batched_spec = structure.type_spec_from_value(element)
   4553   self._tensors = structure.to_batched_tensor_list(batched_spec, element)
...
    100     dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
    101 ctx.ensure_initialized()
--> 102 return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)

 

InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.

 

ime/bfc_allocator.cc:1063] Next region of size 10919346176
2022-08-29 07:30:29.597096: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 7f86a6000000 of size 7864320000 next 1
2022-08-29 07:30:29.597127: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 7f887ac00000 of size 1280 next 2
2022-08-29 07:30:29.597140: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 7f887ac00500 of size 256 next 3
2022-08-29 07:30:29.597151: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 7f887ac00600 of size 256 next 4
2022-08-29 07:30:29.597163: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] Free  at 7f887ac00700 of size 3055024384 next 18446744073709551615
2022-08-29 07:30:29.597174: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1088]      Summary of in-use Chunks by size: 
2022-08-29 07:30:29.597188: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1091] 2 Chunks of size 256 totalling 512B
2022-08-29 07:30:29.597203: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1091] 1 Chunks of size 1280 totalling 1.2KiB
2022-08-29 07:30:29.597215: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1091] 1 Chunks of size 7864320000 totalling 7.32GiB
2022-08-29 07:30:29.597227: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 7.32GiB
2022-08-29 07:30:29.597238: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1097] total_region_allocated_bytes_: 10919346176 memory_limit_: 10919346176 available bytes: 0 curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 21838692352
2022-08-29 07:30:29.597953: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] Stats: 
Limit:                     10919346176
InUse:                      7864321792
MaxInUse:                   7864321792
NumAllocs:                           4
MaxAllocSize:               7864320000
Reserved:                            0
PeakReserved:                        0
LargestFreeBlock:                    0

 

2022-08-29 07:30:29.597981: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:491]
```

The first line of the error seems very weird :

```
Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 29.17GiB (rounded to 31323193344)requested by op _EagerConst
```

**Why the allocator try to allocate 30Go while my data actually are of 500Mo ?**

I already have try to watch the GPU usage in real time using `watch -n 0.5 nvidia-smi` but all the values seems normal.

Comment: I'm not sure where you get 500MB. I get: 80000 * 128*128*3 (assuming 3 color channels) * 4 (assuming `float32` datatype). This is the total number of bytes. Divide by 1024 three times (convert to KB -> MB -> GB) and you get around 12.5GB. Now, if your numpy array is actually `float64`, that would double to about 25GB.

Comment: Note, I had a mistake in my computation, you actually end up with about 29GB for `float64` which matches the error message.

Comment: You right, I just convert all my data to float16 and the size is now of ~7Go

Comment: Note that the difference from 500MB might come from the images being saved in some compressed format (e.g. JPEG), but when they are loaded into arrays they are decompressed and will take much more space.

Comment: Yes this is just the difference between compressed and uncompressed data.